# Prevent user from reading javascript data and files when login fails

Tags: javascript, security, angularjs

I have an application which is written in angularjs. However, this problem applies to javascript applications in general.

The user calls the index.html in the browser, which then presents him the login page. However, in the background, all javascript files are being already loaded. Therefore the user could in theory read the code (even when obfuscated and minified) and gain important information (keywords, rest call urls and so on). Even if I would do lazy loading of js files, the user still can lookup the js source path and pull it from the server. Is there a way to prevent a user from doing so?

EDIT: or is there at least a way to prevent the user from seeing the js source before has successfully authenticated himself (no prevention of reading the rest api url)? My application contains data (data!=rest call data but Strings in the application itself) which one should not know when he is not authenticated.

Answer (score 3):

In my current apllication I use PHP for the REST part. So it's pretty easy to have index.php handle the login in a classical way and if the user logged in i'll head to the actual Angular App.

All my REST functions do a logged_in check and if it fails, head back to index.php. Also my partials are PHP templates that do checks for Login, Rights and Ownership that chicken out if something is wrong or just don't include crucial script parts or replace them with something that the user is allowed to see.

So everything security related is handled on the server side, all the convenience on the client side.

And yep, i can live with the fact that a hacking attempt or a failed login reloads the minimal login page.

Comment: You wrote that "if the user logged in i'll head to the actual Angular App". Do you prevent a user from getting your angular js source without being logged in? As an example the login page is test.com/login.php and the angularjs is under test.com/myapp.html. The user could do a wget test.com/myapp.html and then read the path of the js sources and get those. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would call the angular app myapp.php. Do a logged_in check in PHP and if this goes wrong echo something like: 'Go away stoopid HaXoR!" or head back to login.php without further notification. A valid logged_in gets the correct page and the user can of course see the sources, routes and can even debug them. If i want to hide something from him, because he does not have the rights, I'll prevent this in the partials/template_xxx.php. This worked for me very well, I haven't found an illegal way in my app so far. But this is just a suggestion.

Comment: The crucial part is: The hacker/illegal user should never get anything from doing a call to the rest api. So he may be able to see the sources, but he can not access your database and get any Information. Let him see your sources and make him awe at your genius coding skills, but dont give him any usefull information about your seversided data:-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. Even if the user don't have access to the JavaScript files, he can monitor the traffic between his browser and the server so he would be aware of the communication protocol and all REST calls.

Comment: +1: I agree with the REST call part. If you would ignore this part, how would you prevent one from reading the js code without being logged in?

Comment: Well, if the login page does not use AngularJS but is standard HTML for instead the unauthorized used won't have access to the JavaScript. Once he login you can provide him the AngularJS application.

Comment: Then I have configure the web server in a way that it prevents the user from loading the js data without being logged in. If not, then the user still could load the js data (it is then more a path guessing since the login html has no reference to the next url if the authentication is successful).