# User login system with mySQL database with Angular JS?

Tags: php, mysql, database, angularjs, authentication

I'm trying to create a user login system where each user has a password, a username and a level (I.E Admin or Master). What i've done so far:

Created a mySQL database using PHP and created the relevant fields in the tables.

Made a simple Angular JS page.

I'm trying to link the database and page so I can check a user's input in the login inpuot field against all the data stored in the 'passwords' section of my mySQL table.

Any idea how I can achieve this? The most simplest, straight-forward answers please as I'm new to Angular (and mySQL!)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create some server side code (in your case, probably in php) to do the actual database operations, then call this code with Angular's $http or $resource.

Comment: How about creating a form with angular, posting the data to a php script and validate the login data? But try it out yourself ;) If you have some code and problems with it, then come back and ask again!

Comment: I'll try using  $_POST to get the form inputs and then connecting it to Angular. Thanks for the swift replies everyone! :)

Comment: I'm getting greatly confused. All I want to do is test what a user inputs (their username) against my database table when the 'login/submit' button is pressed. And then check if their password is correct if the username is found. I'm very very very confused if anyone could spell it out in extremely simple terms with code snippets/ examples if possible I would be eternally grateful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not do a login on an angular page since everything data related is handled by javascript which can easily be stopped, debugged and analyzed.

The better way would be:

1. Create a normal index.php which presents a login form to the user.
2. On submit check for validity with your database.
3. If user is valid start a session and `header` on to the actual angular app page.
4. The only way to check if this is a valid `php session` is in your `REST` calls via angular `http` service to your database related php scripts.
5. So every read/write access to your `REST api` should check, if this user is really allowed to do this db operation in the php script.
6. If the check fails, `header` back to the login page or some "Got you!" page.

This way the attackor may be able to see the js code of the angular app (if he gets somehow hold of the actual address) but it's completely useless to him, cause he can never see the actual data as long as he hadn't started a valid `php session`. And the data is what you want to protect, not the script of the app.

In a nutshell: Mix standard PHP validation AND Angular. Allow haxors to get to your page, but never, ever show them any of your underlying data. As soon as someone tries to mess with your data, kick him out.

This is nearly the same answer i gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572534/prevent-user-from-reading-javascript-data-and-files-when-login-fails/21573893#21573893)

Search for the marked keywords in both PHP and Angular sites to grasp the idea behind this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and let you know how I get on. :)